# Neural network with genetic algorithm question

Tags: c++, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

Since this question is going to quite long you can read cliff notes at the bottom, or read the full text here.
I'm playing around with genetic algorithms and neural networks (i.e. using genetic algorithms to evolve neural networks) but I'm encountering a few problems, in particular I find the evolution extremely slow to converge and often not converging at all towards the desired results! Yet, since there are so many settings (population size, mutation rate, crossover rate, and so on...) I don't know if this is due to some bugs in my code or because I made a poor choice of those aforementioned parameteres. Or maybe I'm expecting results too early when it is normal for this kind of networks to be so slow.

Now some examples:
Training a net to make the sum of two numbers, providing a training set with 20 examples and a genetic algorithm with the following settings:

```
#define MUTATION_RATE       0.5
#define MAX_PERTURBATION    1
#define POP_SIZE            500
#define CROSSOVER_RATE      0.7
#define NUM_TOUR            35
#define ELITISM             4
```

Where NUM_TOUR is the number of individuals selected to run a tournament and ELITISM is the number of copies I make of the best individual of the current generation to propagate it to the next one.
With these settings and a network with just 2 input and 1 output neurons I'm able to train it to give the sum of two numbers pretty accurately after 2500 generations (which seems like a hell of a lot to me, but whatever), like:

```
2 + 2 = 4.01
```

Or

```
1 + 5 = 5.98
```

Using the same settings, and a network with 2 input, 1 output, and 1 hidden layer of 2 neurons, I try to make it learn how to multiply two numbers: after 2500 generations I don't get anywhere near a good result (like: `0 * 10 = 3.7`).

I didn't try any other operation since I guess that if I can't come up with a network which learns how to multiply there is either something wrong with my code or with my settings. As I said I'm using tournament selection, the crossover is implemented by chosing each gene with equal probability from one of the two parents, and the mutation by adding or subtracting a value from 0 to `MAX_PERTURBATION` to the current value.

Is there anything I'm doing glaringly wrong? Can you point me out to any tutorial discussing how to optimize the use of genetic algorithm with neural networks (what kind of crossover works best, what kind of population size is better, also mutation rate, and so on...) Or can give me any tips?

I'm creating a neural network which gets trained with genetic algorithms but it's behaving very poorly, not even being able to learn how to multiply two numbers. Some examples are shown in the complete text.

Comment: How many weights will an individual have? My specialty is in GAs, not NNs, and I gave up trying to figure it out after a while. That will impact the question of whether your mutation rate is appropriate.

Comment: Each invididual has a number of weights equal to the total number of weights in the network, so with 2 input 2 hidden and 1 output neuron it has 6 weights. Anyway I fixed a bug in my code which led to many  duplicated individuals, and this solved much of the problem, although I'm still looking to general guidelines on how to choose parameters for the GA.

Answer (score 3):

I did a lot of research on evolutionary design of neural networks and I'd like to give some hints.

Start with the simplest algorithm and not with a GA which has a lot of parameters: start with random search, simulated annealing and Evolution Strategies which usually works a lot better of GA when crossover leads to destructive effects! In NN design crossover is not always effective because it tends to 'destroy' learning patterns. You can implement ES with few lines of code and Simulated Annealing is already implemented in MATLAB. Do NOT use GA only because it's already implemented in MATLAB. At least keep it simple, remove crossover and elitism and unusual selection mechanisms.

Moreover, you must compare always your algorithm with  good neural network training algorithm, in this way you'll know when a problem it's too hard (or nearly impossible) for a specific neural network.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in neural networks, but in my memory the neuron behavior is linear, that is the output is the sum of inputs multiplicated by coefficients. What the genetic algorithm wants to find are these coefficients. Given only two neurons, I don't think you can compute multiplication since the inputs operands will never get multiplicated together during the computation, unless you connect a neuron output to a neuron coefficient.

My intuition tells me you need more neurons to do it, in order to the virtual brain approximate the multiplication by multiple linear operations. May be you'll also have to introduce a non linear operation in your virtual neuron, such as output value clamping.

Comment: There are nonlinear response neurons too. Sigmoidal are pretty usual. If he where to use a multiplicative neuron this would actually be easy...

Answer (score 0):

Your tournament size, at 35, is *very* high. With a tournament size that large, on a population of 500, you're actually going to wiping out a lot of your diversity every generation. 7 would be a fairly typical tournament size, with 3-11 the typical range.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. Anyway there was a bug in my code I just fixed and this almost solved the problem, although I'm still looking to general guidelines on how to choose parameters like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that neural network is too small. Try adding more neurons in hidden layer and also try adding one more layer.